# How to change background color on Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am new to react native, i have simple `app.js` file

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="CLick Me"/>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}


var styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: randomHex(),
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
}

function randomHex() {
  console.log("Func Called")
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};
```

in here i have a simple function `randomHex` which gives a random hex color, when i refresh my app on my web the color is update but is there any way when i click the button the background color is updated with any random color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably better ways of doing this. But one way is to use states. The answer above mine only runs the function "randomHex()" which returns the color, but I don't think it will change the background color.

Instead I would probably use the useState hook. This will allow the component to change the background color when the state is changed.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState(randomHex());

  var styles = {
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
  };

  function randomHex() {
    console.log("Func Called");
    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: bgColor }]}>
      <Button title="Click Me" onPress={() => setBgColor(randomHex())} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

All I have done, is add the import for the state with React. Then also added a state called bgColor and the function to change this value setBgColor. Whenever bgColor is changed, the view will change it's background color.

Comment: Thanks this worked, and explaination was also good

Answer (score 0):

VERY SIMPLE:

```
function btnClick(e){
   styles.container.backgroundColor=randomHex()
}
<Button title="CLick Me" onPress={btnClick} />
```

I think This Should Work. If not contact me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good with functional components but this works:

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        color: randomHex()
    }
    onClick = () => {
        this.setState({ color: randomHex() })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ ...styles.container, backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>
                <Button onPress={this.onClick} title="CLick Me" />
                <StatusBar style="auto" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}


var styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
}

function randomHex() {
    console.log("Func Called")
    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState({
    color: '',
  });

  function randomHex(){
    console.log("Func Called");
    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let random = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        random += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    setColor({
      color: random,
    });
    console.log("New color: "+color.color);
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: color.color }]}>
      <Button title='Change color' onPress={randomHex}/>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

var styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
}
```